# Sending an audio file to the client from the server and playing it

Tags: java, netty

I'm new to netty and I'm trying very hard to figure out how to send a file from the server to the client and play it back.

I searched a lot of information on the internet, then u don't, then I can't figure it out

Comment: What's on the other end?  Is this a web server?

Comment: This is a typical client/server application.

Comment: Then the answer lies in your client application.  It will receive the file using whatever protocol you invent, and it will have to route the audio packets into the audio APIs for that operating system.